# Mac application bundle able to launch multiple instances

Tags: macos, bundle

Question: How to create a Mac application able to open multiple instances by default?

In general, a Mac application bundle maintains a single instance of a Mac program. That is, if I double click on "VLC" it will open the VLC program. If I then double click a second time, it will bring the previous VLC window to the foreground; it will not open a new instance of VLC. But if I run 'open -n' on VLC, it will force VLC to open a second instance.

I am creating a Mac application bundle and would like for a user's second double click to cause a second instance of the application to be launched. I couldn't find any relevant keys for use in Info.plist. Any ideas?

Comment: XCode ? Qt ? Java ? ... ?

Comment: Java application bundled using Oracle's AppBundler: https://java.net/projects/appbundler . Generates 'JavaAppLauncher' binary in .app/Contents/MacOS which performs the launching. The creation of the JavaAppLauncher binary happens in main.m found here: https://java.net/projects/appbundler/sources/svn/show/appbundler/native?rev=34

Comment: JavaAppLauncher is a generic binary launcher for Mac which parses options from Info.plist and then launches Java with those options. Its source code is here: https://java.net/projects/appbundler/sources/svn/show/appbundler/native?rev=34 . I assume that the Launcher is less relevant, and there should be a way to control this single-instance behavior on the Bundle-level. That's why I thought there would be a flag in Info.plist, but I don't see anything relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bundle the `open -n` command inside of a shell script in your application bundle, and let it start your main application.

Comment: Stumbled across this trying to do something similar. It seems to work when the shell script is called directly from the terminal. Pointing CFBundleExecutable in the info.plist at the shell script doesn't seem to work though. Double clicking on icon in finder still only launches one instance. It seems like macos is deliberately stopping this workaround.